# Ignore tfoot table rows when creating Highcharts from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, graph, highcharts

How do i set highcharts to ignore the last row of an html table (Which contains total)? I do not want to include data from the cells within the  tags, as this messes up the graph by creating another line graph for total field.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="internal-table tablesorter" id="heythere">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Internal</th>

            <th>Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>

            <td>20</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>2</th>

            <td>20</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>3</th>

            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="total">Total</td>

            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
        $('#dc-graph').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('heythere')
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Lato',
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'INTERNAL PERFORMANCE',
                style: {
                    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '0.8rem',
                    letterSpacing: '1px'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                lineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
                tickColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
                labels: {
                    format: 'Internal #{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                    }
                },

            }

            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `endRow` parameter which define max row.

More parameters are described in the header of [file](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js)